# Matplotlib - change colour based on series/subarray/slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a scatter plot of a series of x,y pairs, where each series has a different colour. My input is a 3-dimensional numpy array of shape 2x3x10. In other words: three different sets of 10 x,y pairs each. This minimal example generates the pairs from a bivariate normal distribution, but as you can see my attempts at plotting the series either result in no colour differentiation between the series, or I end up with many different colours (10 perhaps?). To be clear, I'd like to end with three different colours, one for each of the three sets of 10 x,y pairs, or one colour for each slice through the third dimension of the array.

How should I go about doing this? Is there a different way to define colours for matplotlib? Or should I change things earlier on and define multiple 2 dimensional arrays rather than a 3D one? I'm fairly new to programming and even more so to numpy and matplotlib, but from what I've gathered it's good practice to utilise the multidimensionality of arrays to organise things, but any other general guidelines on this front are appreciated.

```
pairs = np.random.multivariate_normal((1,5),[[1,0],[0,1]],(10,3)).T

array([[[ 0.49358789,  0.57551098,  2.7029197 ,  0.9437744 , -0.45122972,
          0.05786102,  1.76313729, -0.72469019,  0.53466069,  0.67888213],
        [ 2.88773234,  1.43831903, -0.7427195 , -0.01451867,  1.56491086,
          1.72596764,  1.3953636 ,  1.67816112,  0.02839967,  0.96014133],
        [ 2.52065319, -0.2485202 ,  1.51877564,  2.31216588,  1.35005209,
          1.30100189,  0.63590115,  0.32281779,  2.14906114,  0.1551461 ]],

       [[ 4.85695486,  6.06754   ,  5.93342725,  3.49327716,  6.69661302,
          6.52707216,  4.61195227,  3.22767035,  4.23710242,  7.19532735],
        [ 5.06087316,  4.29734169,  5.66389379,  4.60574012,  4.96619091,
          4.88981834,  3.65294396,  5.65582142,  6.27162773,  6.67958156],
        [ 5.47524034,  4.8989236 ,  3.96246028,  6.31088811,  5.39779792,
          5.67488569,  4.66692489,  4.17364195,  3.69659271,  5.85626402]]])

# Note that the actual graphics were based on another random sample
# than the one listed above, due to a mistake on my end.

plt.plot(pairs[0],pairs[1],'x');plt.show()
plt.scatter(pairs[0],pairs[1]);plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

pairs = np.random.multivariate_normal((1,5),[[1,0],[0,1]],(10,3)).T

"""
pairs = [
    [
        [ 0.49358789,  0.57551098,  2.7029197 ,  0.9437744 , -0.45122972,
          0.05786102,  1.76313729, -0.72469019,  0.53466069,  0.67888213],
        [ 2.88773234,  1.43831903, -0.7427195 , -0.01451867,  1.56491086,
          1.72596764,  1.3953636 ,  1.67816112,  0.02839967,  0.96014133],
        [ 2.52065319, -0.2485202 ,  1.51877564,  2.31216588,  1.35005209,
          1.30100189,  0.63590115,  0.32281779,  2.14906114,  0.1551461 ]
    ],

    [
        [ 4.85695486,  6.06754   ,  5.93342725,  3.49327716,  6.69661302,
          6.52707216,  4.61195227,  3.22767035,  4.23710242,  7.19532735],
        [ 5.06087316,  4.29734169,  5.66389379,  4.60574012,  4.96619091,
          4.88981834,  3.65294396,  5.65582142,  6.27162773,  6.67958156],
        [ 5.47524034,  4.8989236 ,  3.96246028,  6.31088811,  5.39779792,
          5.67488569,  4.66692489,  4.17364195,  3.69659271,  5.85626402]
    ]
]
"""

colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]


# I put the % operator in the color array index so it rolls over
# to the start of the color array when it runs out of colors
# (when there's more sets than preset colors)
for index, group in enumerate(pairs[0]):
    plt.plot(group, pairs[1][index], "x", color=colors[index % len(colors)])
plt.show()

for index, group in enumerate(pairs[0]):
    plt.scatter(group, pairs[1][index], color=colors[index % len(colors)])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I was looking for! Now I'm wondering though if I can automatically define a random list of colors of an arbitrary length, when I have more than just 3 sets.